# Nautilus after upgrade 16.04

Tags: nautilus

Problem occured after running this command,

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  

uname -a
```

> Linux HQ-OSLAS 4.4.0-89-generic #112-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 31 19:38:41
>   UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I can not run nautilus and cant see my desktop icon

sudo nautilus

> nautilus: symbol lookup error: nautilus: undefined symbol:
>   gnome_bg_set_draw_background

reinstall did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've installed the GNOME desktop (ubuntu-gnome-desktop) you need to open the `GNOME Tweak Tool` and enable the `Icons on Desktop`. Also make sure that your desktop background is a picture file, not just a solid color.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have enabled  the Icons on Desktop in the GNOME Tweak Tool .   Thanks . Its working   But with nautilus i have a problem.  My desktop background is a picture file . I took it from Ubuntu .    Error -->   nautilus: symbol lookup error: nautilus: undefined symbol: gnome_bg_set_draw_background

Comment: In `terminal` type `nautilus -q` then just `nautilus` (no sudo) and do you see any error messages? Control-C, then type `sudo nautilus`, errors? But does Nautilus start both times? Why are you using sudo? Did you try a different picture?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes.I'l try a different picture  .   When i run:   nautilus -q, nautilus, sudo nautilus ,  -->nautilus: symbol lookup error: nautilus: undefined symbol: gnome_bg_set_draw_background ;

Comment: Working. Thank you . I reinstalled GNOME Tweak Tool and change picture.